# automate a telnet session in java using robotframework telnet api

Tags: java, python, session, telnet, robotframework

Is it possible to automate a telnet session in java using robotframework telnet api. Or it works with Python.Not able to find any sample working code

Answer (score 0):

The [official link](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/tags/robotframework-2.5.5/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#preconditions) states clearly:

> Robot Framework runs both on Python and Jython, and you need to have
>   at least one of them to be able to use it. However, some of the
>   provided installers only work with Python, so installing it is always
>   recommended.

Also you can use it with Java too. The [official page](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/svn/tags/robotframework-2.5.5/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-robot-framework-from-java) also mentions:

> Starting from Robot Framework 2.5.2 Robot Framework is also
>   distributed as a standalone jar file that contains both Jython and
>   Robot Framework. This allows command line execution with only Java
>   installed, but the jar file also provides an API for Java usage.